# Pandas dataframe groupby sum while ignoring non-numerical values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like below. The 'LATENCY' column has both numerical and 'NA' characters, that makes groupby() complex.

```
    DEVICE       START_PRICE   LATENCY
0   ab.fxx.in    500           NA
1   ab.fxx.in    500           1    
2   ab.fxx.in    500           5
3   kddo.fxx.in  500           NA
4   kddo.fxx.in  500           5
5   kddo.fxx.in  533           3
6   kddo.fxx.in  533           NA
```

I wanted to group the dataframe by 'DEVICE' value to the sum of 'LATENCY' - by bypassing 'NA' values. I should get the output as below.

```
DEVICE       
ab.fxx.in      6
kddo.fxx.in    8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert `LATENCY` series to numeric before you use `groupby`.

Using `errors='coerce'` ensures you have `NaN` values where conversion is not successful. When you use `groupby.sum`, `pandas` handles these gracefully by ignoring them.

```
df['LATENCY'] = pd.to_numeric(df['LATENCY'], errors='coerce')

res = df.groupby('DEVICE')['LATENCY'].sum().reset_index()

print(res)

        DEVICE  LATENCY
0    ab.fxx.in      6.0
1  kddo.fxx.in      8.0
```